# How to compare footprints of SMD components?

Tags: surface-mount, footprint

How easy is it to compare dimensions and footprints for different size SMT components?

For example, is it possible to compare the footprints of 0603 and 0402 components to determine if I can use an 0402 component on the footprint of an 0603? Or some another parts?

Which software or web services can I use to do this?

Comment: If you're mainly looking for a software recommendation, that's off topic for this site. There is a [Software Recommendations Stackexchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) where it would likely be on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It completely depends on how the footprint for the 0603 part was designed.  Although there are recommended sizes for all of the solder pads for each component, some PCB designers deviate from those standards for particular reasons.  In particular, the pads are often elongated towards the middle of the component precisely to allow a smaller component to be used on that footprint.

This is often done during the prototyping stage to allow maximum flexibility when working with components that are on hand.

That said: you can often make a 0402 component work on a 0603 footprint **IF** you are placing and soldering the component by hand.  I would not expect that an automated Pick and Place machine would be able to do this.

Comment: I know the dimensions of both footprints (0402 and 0603). How I can get model how 0402 component will be look on 0603 footprints. In which software is it possible to do that?

Comment: Simply lay the two components on top of each other in your layout software.  You can then immediately see what they look like.

Comment: Currently I don't use any software. Maybe You can suggest some ?

Comment: photoshop... draw the two components (read the datasheet) and overlay. Inkscape (same as above... I have the majority of packages drawn so I can do pseudo layouts). KiCAD or other ECAD packages

Comment: @JonRB, I asked about special programs. Designed special for such kinds of tasks.

Comment: @KMM and which of those I listed is not a special program?

Comment: @JonRB, I agreed with you. But I mean software for PCB designing.

Comment: @KMM JonRB mentioned KiCad...which is "software for PCB designing".

Comment: @KMM, Any PCB layout software would be able to do this.  If you don't have one now, pick any one you like.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are looking is an image, this might be a good comparaison :

[image]

In this image, on the left side, on bottom is the 0402

On the right side, the blue one is the 0402

The red and blue rectangles are the pads for soldering. As you may see, they cross each other, you might be able to solder a 0402 to a 0603.

Edit : This image was made in [EasyEDA](https://easyeda.com/editor), which I should recommend if you don't have a software to work with.
Edit 2 : Changed the picture, the package was wrong

Comment: It is not correct models. Because the length of 0603 component is 1.6 mm (gap between pads is 0.9 mm), and length of 0402 component is 1 mm. I will try this software. Thanks

Comment: My bad. Wrong package I chose. This should be better right ?

Comment: It looks to me like the top left part is 0603,and bottom left is 0402.  0402 should be smaller than 0603.

Comment: That's an error. Edit : Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I used [Eagle](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/overview) sowtware for comparison this two packages.

And it look like we can use 0402 component on 0603 footprint.
But maybe only by hand soldering.

There is how its look 0603 footprint and two components with dimensions 0402 and 0603:

[image]